# how to merge two arrays into a object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am looking for best ways of doing this. 
I have two arrays:

```
key = [1,2,3];
value = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

The end result I want is an array of map:

```
[{key: 1, value: 'value1'} ,{key: 2, value: 'value2'}, {key: 3, value: 'value3'}]
```

How do I do it the most efficient/clean way using lodash? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you need

```
_.zipObject(key, value);
```

Actually ... no.

Pure Javascript can though:

```
var result = key.map(function(val, index){
  return { key: val, value: value[index] };
});
```

Comment: Where the hell is key coming from?

Comment: @elad.chen `key` is the key (ahem) name as per OP final result he needed.

Comment: Here is the link to the lodash zipObject method referenced in the answer:
https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject. Also check out https://lodash.com/docs#zipObjectDeep for nesting property paths.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711528/es6-merge-two-arrays-into-an-array-of-objects).

```js
const key = [1,2,3];
const value = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

const output = _.zipObject(key, value);

console.log(output);
/*
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": "value2"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "value": "value3"
  }
]
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This should be marked as a duplicate (cannot do this until you have 15 rep, I believe). For that reason, this would be best posted as a comment.

Comment: Actually, after reading the duplicate, thank heaven this was written by someone who made it so clean and quickly readable. The answer in the link just scrambled my brain.